# .NET Profiler - Filter out .Net Framework Functions

Tags: c#, clr-profiling-api

I've created a .NET Profiling DLL that implements the `ICorProfilerCallback3` interface.

I'm using the profiling to trace the functions called during Runtime, however, I'm looking to trace application specific functions, not the standard .NET framework functions.

I successfully used the `SetEnterLeaveFunctionHook` method and supply it with callback functions.

Then while I'm in the callback functions, I get the function information and assembly information using the `GetFunctionInfo` and `GetModuleInfo2` functions.

The issue I'm running into is this obviously gets called for EVERY function and I'm looking for a way to distinguish between a .Net framework DLL and not a standard DLL.

For instance the majority of calls when the application starts goes to the `mscorlib.dll` which I'm not interested in tracing.

Any thoughts or ideas? I've tried call this function but `pdwImplFlags` doesn't appear to populate with anything useful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/metadata/imetadataimport-getmethodprops-method

Comment: The profiler API probably doesn't distinguish among modules in this way. Could you post-process the results?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`SetFunctionIDMapper2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/profiling/icorprofilerinfo3-setfunctionidmapper2-method) to specify a mapper which checks to see if the function is of interest and return false in `pbHookFunction` if it's not. Then you should only get callbacks for the methods where you returned true in `pbHookFunction`.

Comment: Thats an interesting solution. Appreciate the response. I feel like I would still run into the same problem. I'm not sure how to distinguish between a function I want and a function I don't want. I still would need a way to differentiate between a .NET framework function and a non framework function for the mapper.

Comment: I would probably go with a 'whitelist' of assemblies that gets given to the profiler. Or you could make the decision based on the location of the assembly.

Comment: The location of the assembly makes sense. I really would of thought there would be some type of flag or API call to make it a little bit cleaner. Guess not.

Comment: The other option is to exclude by namespace, for example System.* etc